# Connecting to host MySQL from a Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to connect to MySQL on my host machine from a Docker container. The Docker container has a python file using mysql.connector:

```py
config = {
    'user': 'user',
    'password': 'password',
    'host': '192.168.0.xx',
    'port': 3306,
    'database': 'database'
}
connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
```

When I run this app on a physical computer, it runs perfectly. It is only in the container that it fails. Since user permissions and code is ruled out, I'm guessing that it has something to do with how I run the Docker command:

```bash
sudo docker run --gpus all --rm --network="host" --name house house
```

The error I receive is this:

> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '192.168.0.100:3306', system error: 1 [SSL] internal error (_ssl.c:1131)

I followed the answers from [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach), but it does not solve my problem.